# Distinguish XML Responses

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

**Following Situation:**
I get different XML-formatted responses from a Device. With the response handler class I want to process these responses. Now my problem is how to distinguish these different responses and finding the correct response Type, before deserializing?

**The XML Response Types of the Device**

- Response Type 1: Response

```
<Telegram xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance" xmlns="LancePlatform">
    <Response>
        // The Rest of the XML Tree
    </Response>
</Telegram>
```

- Response Type 2: Notification

```
<Telegram xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance" xmlns="LancePlatform">
    <Notification>
        // The Rest of the XML Tree
    </Notification>
</Telegram>
```

**Process Response Function for One Response Type**

```
public void ProcessResponse(string response)
{
    using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(response))
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Telegram)); 
        Telegram telegram = new Telegram();
        try
        {
            // Do I have to check here if the Deserializion was valid, 
            // and if not try the next Response Type
            telegram = (Telegram)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            Console.WriteLine(telegram.Response);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One way is to have a base class Response with an different inherited class for each type of response.  The response would need an attribute type in xml to distinguish the type and the in the classes a property XmlInclude would be needed to list all the inherited classes.

Comment: The format of the XML are given by the Device (See the edits I made). So how can I distinguish if it's a Response or a Notification with XmlInclude. Could you give an example?

Comment: See update below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then put all the response types into Telegram.  Only one property in the response will have a value and the others will be null

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Telegram telegram = new Telegram();

            string type1 = "<Telegram xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance\" xmlns:p=\"LancePlatform\">" +
                                "<Response>" +
                                //The Rest of the XML Tree
                                "</Response>" +
                            "</Telegram>";


            string type2 = "<Telegram xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance\" xmlns:p=\"LancePlatform\">" +
                                "<Notification>" +
                                //The Rest of the XML Tree
                                "</Notification>" +
                            "</Telegram>";

            Telegram t1 = telegram.ProcessResponse(type1);
            object[] p1 = Telegram.Properties(t1);
            Telegram t2 = telegram.ProcessResponse(type2);
            object[] p2 = Telegram.Properties(t2);
        }
    }
       public class Telegram
    {
        public Response Response { get; set; }
        public Notification Notification { get; set; }

        public static object[] Properties(Telegram t)
        {
            PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(Telegram).GetProperties();

            return properties.Select(x => x.GetValue(t,null)).Where(x => x != null).ToArray();
        }
        public Telegram ProcessResponse(string response)
        {
            Telegram telegram = new Telegram();
            using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(response))
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Telegram));
                try
                {
                    // Do I have to check here if the Deserializion was valid, 
                    // and if not try the next Response Type
                    telegram = (Telegram)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                    Console.WriteLine(telegram.Response);
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }
            }
            return telegram; 
        }

    }
    public class Response
    {
    }
    public class Notification
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I update to add method for getting non null values.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I just get the following Error while casting the return value: `Unable to cast System.Object[] to System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[]`.

Comment: I updated code and tested.  It should be object[] instead of PropertyInfo[]

Comment: Very nice! Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Not very beautiful but what is with:

```
if(response.StartsWith("<ResponseType_1>"))
{
  responseType = typeof(ResponseType_1);
}
else if(response.StartsWith("<ResponseType_2>"))
{
  responseType = typeof(ResponseType_2);
}
```

in front of the using?

Comment: I already thought about that, too. But I thought, that there's maybe a more elegant solution.